# Getting the value from data-* in js

Tags: javascript, html

How come when I click on a button, it returns the value in the parent section, which is `test-calculate-keys123`? How do I get it to return the value that corresponds to the button clicked. That is the section with the class of `calculatorKeys` even though I separated it into `operationKey`, `numberKey`, and `calculateKey`?

And also, is there a simpler way to do it instead of having 4 `addeventlisteners`?

```js
document.querySelector(".calculatorKeys").addEventListener("click", clickButton);
document.querySelector(".operationKey").addEventListener("click", clickButton);
document.querySelector(".numberKey").addEventListener("click", clickButton);
document.querySelector(".calculateKey").addEventListener("click", clickButton);

function clickButton() {
  let key = this.dataset.key
  console.log(key);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
      <section class="equationDisplay display">test</section>
      <section class="answerDisplay display answerFont">
        <div class="answer">0</div>
      </section>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <section class="calculatorKeys" data-key="test-calculate-keys123"> // console logs this value???
        <section class="keyContainer operationKeyContainer">
          <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="divide">÷</button>
          <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="multiply">&times;</button>
          <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="add">+</button>
          <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="subtract">–</button>
        </section>
        <section class="keyContainer numberKeyContainer">
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="7">7</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="8">8</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="9">9</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="4">4</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="5">5</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="6">6</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="1">1</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="2">2</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="3">3</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="0">0</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key=".">.</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="C">C</button>
        </section>
        <section class="keyContainer calculateKeyContainer">
          <button class="calculateKey teal" data-key="calculate">=</button>
        </section>
      </section>
    </main>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: 1. You need `querySelectorAll()` instead and iterate over the resulting list to add the click handler to all buttons 2. click events propagate to parent elements, you can prevent that though by calling `.stopPropagation()` on the click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` keyword in your event handler will always refer to the element you bind the event listener to.

The thing with events is that they bubble, so clicking inside the `calculatorKeys`, let's say one on of the buttons, will cause the event to be fired on the button and bubble up. Once it reaches the `calculatorKeys` element it will be captured because of your event listener. There you can access the `Event` object and check which button is pressed.

This method is called event delegation and allows you to keep event listeners at a minimum.

The example below uses this technique. Within the event handler you can check the `target` property on the `Event` object to get the element that has been clicked. Then check if that clicked element has the `dataset.key` property and log it if it does.

```js
document.querySelector(".calculatorKeys").addEventListener("click", clickButton);

function clickButton(event) {
  if ('key' in event.target.dataset) {
    let key = event.target.dataset.key;
    console.log(key);
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 66px !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>
      <section class="equationDisplay display">test</section>
      <section class="answerDisplay display answerFont">
        <div class="answer">0</div>
      </section>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <section class="calculatorKeys" data-key="test-calculate-keys123"> // console logs this value???
        <section class="keyContainer operationKeyContainer">
          <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="divide">÷</button>
          <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="multiply">&times;</button>
          <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="add">+</button>
          <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="subtract">–</button>
        </section>
        <section class="keyContainer numberKeyContainer">
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="7">7</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="8">8</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="9">9</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="4">4</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="5">5</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="6">6</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="1">1</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="2">2</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="3">3</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="0">0</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key=".">.</button>
          <button class="numberKey" data-key="C">C</button>
        </section>
        <section class="keyContainer calculateKeyContainer">
          <button class="calculateKey teal" data-key="calculate">=</button>
        </section>
      </section>
    </main>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. So basically the ```event.target``` captures down from the parent class ```calculatorKeys``` and returns the value of the ```data-*``` attribute. I can read more later on javascript.info but I'm just asking for clarity now.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Listening on the parent means that the parent and all descendants of the parent their events will be captured. They move up the tree (bubbling) until they reach the `calculatorKeys` element where the listener is placed. The event carries information, like the element that triggered the event. Try logging the `event` variable in the function to see what information you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".keyContainer")].forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", clickButton)
});

function clickButton(evt) {
  var key = event.target.dataset.key
  console.log(key);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="equationDisplay display">test</section>
  <section class="answerDisplay display answerFont">
    <div class="answer">0</div>
  </section>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <section class="calculatorKeys" data-key="test-calculate-keys123"> // console logs this value???
    <section class="keyContainer operationKeyContainer">
      <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="divide">÷</button>
      <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="multiply">&times;</button>
      <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="add">+</button>
      <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="subtract">–</button>
    </section>
    <section class="keyContainer numberKeyContainer">
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="7">7</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="8">8</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="9">9</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="4">4</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="5">5</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="6">6</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="1">1</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="2">2</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="3">3</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="0">0</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key=".">.</button>
      <button class="numberKey" data-key="C">C</button>
    </section>
    <section class="keyContainer calculateKeyContainer">
      <button class="calculateKey teal" data-key="calculate">=</button>
    </section>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a data-* value in JavaScript simply do this:

```js
console.log(el.getAttribute("data-something"));
```

You can also set it using this:

```js
el.setAttribute("data-something", "value")
```

In addition, to add multiple event listeners easily simply do this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".calculatorKeys, .operationKey, .numberKey, .calculateKey").forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", clickButton)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

***You could get your button elements with `querySelectorAll()` so you can run a loop over them. Then run a click event listener on the looped element, then you can get the dataset attribute with the event target that is being clicked on.***

**Extra:** *You can then calculate the entries within a conditional that checks varying entries as needed. I added a very basic calculation just to show how it could be done using an array and pushing your entry values into the array. I changed your dataset values for the operators so they could be run through `eval()` when the event listeners conditional is true for an `equals` => `=` entry.*

I used the array to hold the entries, disallowing the equals sign to be passed with a conditional, then converted it to a string within that conditional, removed the commas and evaluated the strings values to get the answer. Reset the array. This is very basic and just used as an example.

```js
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const answer = document.querySelector('.answer');
var keys = [];
btn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let key = e.target.dataset.key;
    if (key !== "=") {
      keys.push(key)
    }
    let calculation = ` ${key}`;
    answer.innerText += calculation;

    if (key === "=") {
      answer.innerText = `${keys.toString().replaceAll(',', '')} = ${eval(keys.toString().replaceAll(',', ''))}`;
      keys = [];
    }
    if (key === "C") {
      keys = [];
      answer.innerText = '';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section class="equationDisplay display"></section>
    <section class="answerDisplay display answerFont">
      <div class="answer"></div>
    </section>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <section class="calculatorKeys" data-key="test-calculate-keys123"> // console logs this value???
      <section class="keyContainer operationKeyContainer">
        <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="/">÷</button>
        <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="*">&times;</button>
        <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="+">+</button>
        <button class="operationKey lightRed" data-key="-">–</button>
      </section>
      <section class="keyContainer numberKeyContainer">
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="7">7</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="8">8</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="9">9</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="4">4</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="5">5</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="6">6</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="1">1</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="2">2</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="3">3</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="0">0</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key=".">.</button>
        <button class="numberKey" data-key="C">C</button>
      </section>
      <section class="keyContainer calculateKeyContainer">
        <button class="calculateKey teal" data-key="=">=</button>
      </section>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```